# PHP preg_match searching efficient

Tags: php, regex

In `PHP` `regex`, I try to come up with a solution in finding strings upon different cases. I have a string which contains words,

```
$animals = "Elephant Horse Cow";
```

Now I want to make some cases using `preg_match()` and not `strpos()` for some reason. I had an array with different strings in it and I want to iterate my array to find the cases. My searching is case-insensitive.

Here are my cases.

1) All animals names present in a string with different order, like

```
$my_case1 = "Horse Elephant Cow";
```

2) Any animal would be present in a string but not case 1 , like

```
$my_case2 = "Horse Elephant";
```

3) Any animal would be present with plural or an extra string after that, like

```
$my_case3 = "Horses";
```

And my array of animals is like,

```
$all_animals = ["Horses Cows", "Elephant", "Goats", "Goat"];
```

I made the cases using `strpos()` but they are un reliable.

**EDIT1: MY CODE**

```
function mySearch($name,$animals)
{
    $my_case1 = array();
    $my_case2 = array();
    $my_case3 = array();
    $all_cases = [];

    $a = explode(' ', $name);
    foreach($a as $key) {

        foreach($animals as $animal) {

        if ($animal !== $key)
        {
            if ((strpos( strtolower($key), str_replace(' ', '', strtolower($animal)) ) !== FALSE) && (strpos( strtolower($key), str_replace(' ', '', strtolower($animal)))) == 0)
            {
                echo $animal. "<br>";
            }
            else if ((strpos( $key, substr( $animal, 0, -1) ) !== FALSE) && (strpos( $key, $animal ) !== 0) )
            {
                echo $animal. "<br>";
            }
        }

        if (strpos(strtolower($animal), strtolower($key)) !== false) {

            if (strpos($animal, $key) !== false) {
                if ($animal !== $key)
                {
                    echo $animal. "<br>";
                }
            } else
            {
               echo $animal. "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
    return $all_cases; // empty as testing is directing my echo
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you used with `strpos`?

Comment: yeah, let me update my question. @chris85

Comment: Why is "Horses Cows" grouped, but "Goats" is seperate?

Comment: Also, might I recommend using https://regex101.com/#pcre

Comment: @SpYk3HH they are example, if user searches Goat, he should be get the Goats.

Comment: What is `$name`? Also what are the `my_case1`, etc. being used for?

Comment: $name is the string which the user will enter for searching.

Comment: So maybe something like http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c37e3fb5ebd92411217195270809cc3ef9978c47 This requires all animals are singular, individually entered, and the plural versions are append with an `s`. Octopi for example wont work.

Answer (score 0):

[strpos()](http://php.net/strpos) is case sensitive.  You want [stripos()](http://php.net/stripos)

Reminder - both of those functions return 0 if the match is at the start of the string and FALSE if the string can't be found.  To tell the difference requires using the strict comparison operators ( === and !=== )